# Anchor as a Submit button

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC 2 application that has the following on it;

```
    <% using( Html.BeginForm("Results","Quote", FormMethod.Post, new { name="Results" })){ %>
        <% Html.RenderPartial("Needs", Model.needs); %>
        <div class="But green" style="">
            <a href="." onclick="javascript:document.Results.submit();">Go</a>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" />
    <%} %>
```

Pressing the Submit button or the anchor both post back to the right ActionResult.

However, when in the controller I return View(stuff..) only the Submit button will come back to the page.

When the call finishes from pressing the anchor, I go to an error page informing me that the resource cannot be found.

I suspect it has something to do with href="." but am unsure what to set it to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try and just use a `#` in the href - empty in-page link I guess you could call it.

```
<div class="But green" style="">
    <a href="#" onclick="javascript:document.Results.submit();">Go</a>
</div>
```

That way it should work on any page without worrying about specifically setting the href to the view you're trying to return.

Answer (score 0):

I have it.

```
        <div class="But green" style="">
            <a href="Results" onclick="javascript:document.Results.submit();">Go</a>
        </div>
```

href needs to be set to the view i'm trying to return.

Comment: write that as an answer and i'll mark it as correct.  thank you